# Why am I getting an index out of bounds when I try to read certain bytes from a file?

Tags: java, fileinputstream

Can anyone figure out why I'm getting an index out of bounds exception here? I can read in the first lot of data but when I try and loop this again it errors. Im also getting an 'assigned value is never used' error on the is.read(readBytes, offset, length); part of this too.

```
InetAddress address = packet.getAddress();

int port = packet.getPort();

RRQ RRQ = new RRQ();

int offset = 0;
int length = 512;
int block = 0;

byte[] readBytes = new byte[512];

File file = new File(filename);
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

int fileBytes = is.read(readBytes, offset, length);

DatagramPacket outPacket = RRQ.doRRQ(readBytes, block, address, port);
socket.send(outPacket);

block++;

if (fileBytes != -1)
{                   
    socket.receive(packet);

    offset = offset + fileBytes;

    System.out.println(offset);

    Exceptions here:fileBytes = is.read(readBytes, offset, length);

    outPacket = RRQ.doRRQ(readBytes, block, address, port);
    socket.send(outPacket);
    block++;
}
```

Comment: where's `here`? And where's the loop?

Comment: The first read that executes after `offset + length` exceeds 512, would be my guess at the cause of the exception

Answer (score 11):

Look at this call:

```
fileBytes = is.read(readBytes, offset, length);
```

That's fine when `offset` is 0 - but when it's *not* 0, you're asking to read 512 bytes into an array which is only 512 bytes long, but *not* starting at the beginning of the array - therefore there's not enough room for all 512 bytes that you've asked for.

I suspect you want:

```
fileBytes = is.read(readBytes, offset, length - offset);
```

... or alternatively, just leave offset as 0. It's not clear what `RRQ.doRRQ` does, but it's suspicious that you don't pass in `offset`...

Comment: Ah ok I thought that the offset was to tell the Input Stream to read from a certain point in the file. If this is the case then wouldnt the input stream just read from the beginning of the file if the .read() method was used again?

Comment: Typically stream I/O is sequential with a facility in the API to reset the stream pointer, assuming the underlying datasource supports random access.

Comment: @DMo: No, it's to say where to write the data *to* in the array. Read the JavaDoc for more information. The stream maintains its current position. I suggest you read up on stream-based APIs, e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html

Comment: Thanks mate. Much appreciated. I certainly will. I had a look at the JavaDoc for this but looks like I misread it. I'm fairly new to this though so I will for sure read up.